# VirtualMachines.beginRunCommandAndWait always returns 'Provisioning succeeded'

Tags: azure

Can you give me a hint, please?

I call powershell script and when an exception occurs and exitCode > 1 it always returns 'Provisioning succeeded'.

```
code: 'ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded',
      level: 'Info',
      displayStatus: 'Provisioning succeeded',
      message: 'Restart WinAppDriver\n' +
        'Transcript started, output file is C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\WinAppDriver.txt\n' +
        'Transcript stopped, output file is C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\WinAppDriver.txt\n' +
        'Transcript started, output file is C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\WinAppDriver.txt\n' +
        'Downloading WinAppDriver Installer from: https://test/WindowsApplicationDriver_1.2.1.msi\n' +
        'Download completed\n' +
        'Installing WinAppDriver\n' +
        'Installation Failed with Exit Code: 1622\n' +
        'Transcript stopped, output file is C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\WinAppDriver.txt'
    },
```

How do I raise an exception and do I need to raise an exception? Maybe there is another way that was incorporated in the design of the component.
I would like to understand that the script was executed with an error.

Command:

```
$Name = 'WinAppDriver'
$Log = Join-Path $ENV:TEMP "$Name.txt"

Start-Transcript -Append $Log

try
{
    $Dir = get-location
    $File = "WindowsApplicationDriver.msi"
    $TempFolder="temp"
    $Filepath="$Dir\$TempFolder\$File"

    # WinAppDriver Installation
    if (!(Test-Path $TempFolder))
    {
        Write-Host "Creating temp folder at $TempFolder"
        New-Item -Name $TempFolder -Type Directory | Out-Null
    }

    Write-Host "Installing $Name"
    $Process = Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList "/i $Filepath /l*vx log.txt /qn /norestart" -PassThru -wait -NoNewWindow
    if ($Process.exitCode -ne 0) {
        throw "Installation Failed with Exit Code: $($Process.exitCode)"
    }
    Write-Host "Installation Completed with Exit Code: $($Process.exitCode)"
    exit $Process.exitCode
}
Finally{
    Stop-Transcript
}
```

```
Write-Host "error"
exit $Process.exitCode
```

```
throw "error"
exit $Process.exitCode
```

Comment: could you share your comand

Comment: added to the text, but I trimmed it down a bit, leaving only the necessary validation and the basic structure

Comment: Are you looking at the output [like this](https://i.imgur.com/tsN1KyC.png)?"

Comment: yes, and I want (probably) to get it as a componend and display status.

Now it's a 

'ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded',
      level: 'Info',
      displayStatus: 'Provisioning succeeded',

Even script execution is failed.

Comment: if it's possible, of cause

Answer (score 0):

> How do I raise an exception and do I need to raise an exception?

Here is the updated code.

The updated code remove`exit` statements and replaced with a `catch` block that will catch any exceptions thrown by the script and display an error message.

```
$Name = 'WinAppDriver'
$Log = Join-Path $ENV:TEMP "$Name.txt"

Start-Transcript -Append $Log

try
{
    $Dir = get-location
    $File = "WindowsApplicationDriver.msi"
    $TempFolder="temp"
    $Filepath="$Dir\$TempFolder\$File"

    # WinAppDriver Installation
    if (!(Test-Path $TempFolder))
    {
        Write-Host "Creating temp folder at $TempFolder"
        New-Item -Name $TempFolder -Type Directory | Out-Null
    }

    Write-Host "Installing $Name"
    $Process = Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList "/i $Filepath /l*vx log.txt /qn /norestart" -PassThru -wait -NoNewWindow
    if ($Process.exitCode -ne 0) {
        throw "Installation Failed with Exit Code: $($Process.exitCode)"
    }
    Write-Host "Installation Completed with Exit Code: $($Process.exitCode)"
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Error: $_"
    throw $_
}
finally{
    Stop-Transcript
}
```

9000111015
If the installation fails, the code will throw an exception with the message **Installation failed with Exit Code** `$($Process.exitCode)`. otherwise, the code will write a message to the console indicating that the Installation completed.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: "The problem, that I'm getting ""Installation Failed with Exit Code: $($Process.exitCode)" but returns as a successfully provisioned job (why not failed also?):

code: 'ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded',
      level: 'Info',
      displayStatus: 'Provisioning succeeded',
      message: 'Restart WinAppDriver\n' +
        'Installing WinAppDriver\n' +
        'Installation Failed with Exit Code: 1622\n' +
    },

Comment: The problem is that the exit statement in your code is preventing the exception from being thrown. When the exit statement is executed, the script will immediately stop executing, and the exception will not be propagated to the calling code. Try without exit statement.

Comment: "{code:'ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded',level:'Info',displayStatus:'Provisioningsucceeded',message:'InstallationFailedwithExitCode:1622\\n'+'AtC:\\\\Packages\\\\Plugins\\\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\\1.1.15\\\\Downloads\\\\script0.ps1:60char:9\\n'+'+throw\"InstallationFailedwithExitCode:$($Process.exitCod...\\n'+'+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\n'+'+CategoryInfo:OperationStopped:(InstallationFailedwithExitCode:1622:String)[],RuntimeException\\n'+'+FullyQualifiedErrorId:InstallationFailedwithExitCode:1622\\n'+''}" 
The same :(

Comment: Have you tried 'mode'? For me, I'm getting an exception with a 'failed' state, not a 'success' state, with the same code.

Comment: What the 'mode'? is it a beginruncommandandwait parameter?
Any links on Azure documentation, please?

Comment: Sry not mode, Have you tried my code?

Comment: Yes, and the result in the previous comment. Success instead of Failed.